# SPFx Document Web Part Deprecated?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to extend the functionality of the Documents web part

I have been trying to gulp serve this: [Documents Web Part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-documents-detailslist).

But it is over 2 year old and localhost refuses to work (`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL`), I have set `NODE_ENV` to production and `NODE_NO_HTTP2=1`.

I just want someone to run the sample as my work is extending it.

**EDIT: I have it working locally by disabling https and removing the s in https from initpage in serve.json - however this disables the web part from running on work bench, any ideas?**

Comment: whenever you use any existing project in spfx, just do a "npm install"  and then do whatever you want to.

Comment: Yes if you try it yourself you will that most of the deps are deprecated and so even local host does not work. @harshalgite